# Start Fragment From Back Button Within An Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to **override the back button in an activity** so that I can start a fragment, normally within activities I use an intent but as I understand I cannot use an intent to call fragments.

The reason I want to use the back button to start the intent is so it can reload new information from the database, otherwise, if I don't override the back button it will just load the previous fragment with old (cached) data.

My code below which does not work:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

    new leftRoom().execute();

    Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityChatRoom.this,Fragment_01_Rooms.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Update:**

fragment_01_rooms.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- android:background="@color/gray_header"-->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Update (activity_main.xml):

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/viewpager" 
tools:context=".FragmentMain" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

    new leftRoom().execute();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.viewpager, new Fragment_01_Rooms()).commit();

}
```

You would have to add a `FrameLayout` as the container in the activity if you don't already have a container view in which to inflate the fragment. Let me know if you need more clarifications.

**EDIT**

Thanks a lot for the full activity code. Since you are using a `ViewPager`, replacing a fragment this way won't work. Now, you mentioned two lines in the onBackPressed you wanted to implement:

```
 handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); 
 new leftRoom().execute();
```

What is the role of these two methods and where are they implemented? If these methods update your db, and if `Fragment_01_Rooms` is the leftmost element in your `viewPager`, I would suggest you to do this:

1. In the `onResume` of your `Fragment_01_Rooms`, refresh the data that you are going to show the user (if the two lines above already refresh the data, you don't need to do anything).
2. In the Activity, override onBackPressed and call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(0)` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager...commit()`.

Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: I get "container cannot be resolved or is not a field" I tried adding android:id="@+id/container" to fragment_01_rooms.xml, did not work.

Comment: It wouldn't. As I mentioned in my answer, you need to add a `FrameLayout` to the `Activity` in which you want to inflate this `Fragment`.  This `FrameLayout` should have the id "container". I would be able to help you better if you post the XML of your `Activity`.

Comment: I have an update with with contents of fragment_01_rooms.xml

Comment: No, I need the XML of your activity, not your fragment. The activity in which you are overriding `onBackPressed()`. I'm really sorry for the late reply.

Comment: I made an update with activity_main.xml, I'm using ViewPager to handle the fragments

Comment: "No view found for id 0x7f090013.. id/viewpager for for Fragment_01_Rooms.

Comment: Can you paste a little more of the log cat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114549/discussion-between-ishita-sinha-and-user3560827).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    new leftRoom().execute();
}
```

In your leftRoom AsyncTask onPostExecute call this.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new Fragment_01_Rooms()).commit();
```